# Can you put a SQLite table name as a string format?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code and I am wondering what the security implications are as far as SQL injection:

```
with connection as con:
    cur.execute("SELECT count(user_id) FROM {} WHERE document_id=?".format(db_table), (document_id,))
```

Thanks

Comment: You obviously already know how to safely provide parameters to a SQL statement; you're doing it with `document_id`.  Why would you not do exactly the same thing with the table name?  ANY string interpolation presents exactly the same security risk.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am still learning this and I am not sure if you can you the same "?" notation for the table name.  The table name changes depending on a parameter from a function.